# Taking now seriously (rather than tense)

Tags: reference-request, time, mctaggart

McTaggert says [time](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/) includes an "irreducible" A series, of the past present and future flowing on like we're used to.

I think he says that the A series cannot exist so time isn't real.

> McTaggart argued that there is in fact no such thing as time,

What philosophical evidence is there that this "A series" is real?

I ask because I maybe think that while I do seem to experience an A series, that I only really need commit to:

1. now, and
2. not now.

And I seem more inclined to accept that while something both is and isn't now, as per the style of McTaggart's argument against the A series, the terms are utterly primitive and unanalyzable and so this is no contradiction.

Does any philosophical text take this approach in an interesting way?

Comment: Also where does mctaggart subscribe himself to the A-theory?

Comment: ah yeah poorly worded

Comment: Have you read McTaggart's Unreality of Time paper? It starts p457 here https://archive.org/details/mindpsycho17edinuoft/page/456 & it's only 18 pages.